# localhost always redirect to localhost/projects directory in wampserver

Tags: apache, localhost, wampserver

I get some weird issue that every time I typed "localhost" in my address bar it always redirect to localhost/projects.

I already change configuration in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp"
<Directory "c:/wamp">
```

and in httpd-vhost.conf

```
DocumentRoot c:/wamp
<Directory  "c:/wamp/">
```

and in etc/hosts file as below

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 lmlicenses.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 lm.licenses.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 na1r.services.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 hlrcv.stage.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.com 
127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com
```

*Note: I already remove pure Wampserver from my machine, this case still happen.

I don't know where to check this problem anymore. please help. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: _I already change configuration in httpd.conf_ Should read ___I already messed up the configuration in httpd.conf___ Put it back the way it was

Comment: Sorry, RiggsFolly, even I put the original file back or reinstall, it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

1. check httpd.conf
2. check vhost
3. clear DNS lookup in etc/host
4. clear all cache